# C++ stream, function declaration, and other questions

Tags: c++, function, stream

### Iobuffer.cpp

```
#include "Iobuffer.h"

    IOBuffer::IOBuffer (int maxBytes){
    Init (maxBytes);
    }

    IOBuffer & IOBuffer :: operator = (const IOBuffer & buffer){
        if(MaxBytes< buffer.BufferSize) return *this;//fail
        Initialized = buffer.Initialized;
        BufferSize = buffer.BufferSize;
        memcpy(Buffer, buffer.Buffer, buffer.BufferSize);
        NextByte = buffer.NextByte;
        Packing = Packing;
        return *this;
    }

    void IOBuffer::Clear(){
        NextByte = 0;
        Packing = true;
    }

    void IOBuffer::Print(ostream & stream) const{
        stream<<"MaxBytes "<<MaxBytes<<" BufferSize "<<BufferSize;
    }

    int IOBuffer::Init (int maxBytes){
        Initialized = false;
        if (maxBytes < 0) maxBytes = 0;
        MaxBytes = maxBytes;
        Buffer = new char[MaxBytes];
        BufferSize = 0;
        Clear ();
        return 1;
    }

    int IOBuffer::DRead(istream & stream, int recref){
        stream.seekp(recref, ios::beg);
        if(stream.tellp() != recref) return -1;
        return Write(stream);
    }

    static const char * headerStr = "IOBuffer";
    static const int headerSize = strlen(headerStr);

    int IOBuffer::ReadHeader(istream & stream){
        char str[9];
        stream.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        stream.read(str, headerSize);
        if(!stream.good()) return -1;
        if(strncmp(str,headerStr, headerSize)==0) return headerSize;
        else return -1;
}

    int IOBuffer::WriteHeader (ostream & stream) const{
        stream.seekp(0, ios::beg);
        stream.write(headerStr, headerSize);
        if(!stream.good()) return -1;
        return headerSize;
}
```

### its accompanied Iobuffer.h

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
    class IOBuffer{
    public:
        IOBuffer (int maxBytes = 1000);
        IOBuffer & operator = (const IOBuffer &);
        virtual void Clear ();
        virtual int Pack (const void * field, int size = -1) = 0;
        virtual int Unpack (void * field, int maxbytes = -1) = 0;
        virtual void Print(ostream &) const;
        int Init (int maxBytes);
        virtual int Read (istream & x) = 0;
        virtual int Write (ostream & x) const = 0;
        virtual int DRead(istream &, int recref);
        virtual int DWrite(ostream &, int recref) const;
        virtual int ReadHeader (istream &);
        virtual int WriteHeader (ostream *);
    protected:
        int Initialized;
        char * Buffer;
        int BufferSize;
        int MaxBytes;
        int NextByte;
        int Packing;
    };
```

This is an assignment from my File Systems course. In Iobuffer.h, `#include <iostream>` is there because I supposed it would fix the "ostream" or "istream" "has not been declared" errors I am getting from the virtual; Print, Read, Write, DRead, DWrite, ReadHeader, and WriteHeader function prototypes. Those are the only errors from that file. The errors in the .cpp file correlate somewhat, I get the same "istream" and "ostream have not been declared" errors. Any help is much appreciate, let me know if further detail is needed.

-Macaire

*Update, Sir Charlesworth's suggestion cut down the errors exponentially. In the header file  for WriteHeader's virtual function prototype "candidate is: virtual int IOBuffer::WriteHeader(std::ostream*)" error is generated. 

    The remaining 5 errors are in the .cpp file, three of them from DRead's definition(one from each line). The first line says

```
â€˜struct std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >â€™ has no member named â€˜seekpâ€™
```

On a side note why is that formatting so foreign? I looked up `ostream` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/seekp/) at cplusplus.com, and I suppose it could be because I am using an integer as my seek offset. Continuing, the following line says

```
â€˜struct std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >â€™ has no member named â€˜tellpâ€™
```

The return statement says something that is very curious,

```
no matching function for call to â€˜IOBuffer::Write(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)â€™
```

The final error is prototype for

```
â€˜int IOBuffer::WriteHeader(std::ostream&) constâ€™ does not match any in class â€˜IOBufferâ€™
```

and yes that was 5 not 6 error.

Comment: This should probably have the **homework** tag...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most names in the standard library live within the namespace `std`.  So common practice is simply to fully qualify them when you use them (`std::ostream` instead of `ostream`, and so on).

A less recommended approach is to declare `using namespace std;`, which will pull the entire `std` namespace into whatever scope you're currently in (to save you the trouble of writing `std::` every time).  Note that it is considered *extremely* bad practice to have `using namespace ...` declarations in header files.  These should be reserved for source files only.

**UPDATE**

The majority of your new error messages are because you've confused `istream` and `ostream`.  `istream` has a function called `seekg`, not `seekp`, for instance.

Comment: Oli, you could be more clear that your recommendation is to use `std::ostream`. By listing the non-recommended alternative first you confuse the issue.

Comment: @Rob: Indeed. Answer has been rearranged!

Comment: @Malaken: See my updated answer, which addresses your new error messages.

Answer (score 2):

Your last two errors are `const` problems.

You're getting the second-to-last error because you're calling `Write`, which is a const function, from `DRead`, which is a non-const function. You could probably remove `const` from the declaration for `Write`, but make sure that you do the same in all classes that derive from it, too!

You're getting the last error because `IOBuffer.cpp` uses a const definition—`int IOBuffer::WriteHeader (ostream & stream) const`—but `IOBuffer.h` uses a non-const declaration—`virtual int WriteHeader (ostream *);`. You need to choose one or the other (i.e. they either both need to have `const` at the end or neither).

Are you confused about how to use `const`? Is there any particular reason you're declaring your writing functions as `const` and your reading functions as non-`const`? Usually it's the other way around...

For more information, check out [this article on const-correctness](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html) and in particular the question ["What is a const member function?"](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.10).

Comment: I apologize sir I did not read the whole post, the error was from trying to write to an input stream. I called Write when I should have called read.

Comment: @Malaken No problem, but do read up on [const-correctness](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html) if you're going to be doing a lot of programming in C++. It will save you many hours that would otherwise be spent trying to figure out why your code doesn't compile.  :)